# Python-Selenium: Wait for an element to exist then return True or false

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, webdriverwait

I am trying to create a function to help determine if an element appears or disappears from a web page.

This is what I have.

```
def wait_for_element_to_exist(driver, by, seconds=15, negative=False):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, seconds)

    # waiting for element to exist
    if not negative:
        try:
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(*by))
            return True
        except:
            return False

    #wait for element not to exist
    else:
        try:
            wait.until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located(*by))
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

Only thing is that it always returns FALSE no matter how how call it or if the element is present

`wait_for_element_to_exist(self.driver, (By.XPATH, 'xpath'))`
returns `False`

`wait_for_element_to_exist(self.driver, (By.CLASS, 'class'), negative=True)`
returns `False`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: maybe show minimal working code with real URL so we could run it and see problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is with your call on presence_of_element_located(*by)

It's throwing a TypeError, because *by unpacks into two elements, which is one more than it expects. Change `*by` to `by`.

Once you do, if you say on this page,

```
wait_for_element_to_exist(browser, (By.ID, 'question-header'))
```

it returns True

and `wait_for_element_to_exist(browser, (By.ID, 'timeout-header'))`
returns False.

I would recommend changing your `except` to `except TimeoutException` after saying:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

When I have written similar functions, I passed the locate method and the associated string as separate parameters, which may be easier to read and debug.

Comment: doesn't presence_of_element_located take two arguments? The same way find_element() does? I need to keep the by argument as a tuple for sake of other methods that use my wait function. Should I change it to  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_element(*by))

Comment: Ignore that last comment, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is going wrong because you are using a try except block. If Selenium doesn't find the element I don't think it finds an error - it just returns None.

So in similar code I've written in the past for this problem, I've done something like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h2"))
        )

if element:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

So applied to your code that would look like this:

```
def wait_for_element_to_exist(driver, by, seconds=15, negative=False):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, seconds)

    # waiting for element to exist
    if not negative:
        wait_result = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(*by))
        if wait_result:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    #wait for element not to exist
    else:
        wait_result = wait.until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located(*by))
        if wait_result:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Hope that works?

Comment: There is something else going on here. Try Except will give a TimeoutException after the specified number of seconds